# Varrer lista e comparar com uma Array no Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma lista:

```
<ul id="lista">
    <li><span class="datas">01/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">02/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">03/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">04/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">05/01/2020</span></li>
</ul>
```

E um Array de datas:

```
var datas_especiais = ["03/01/2020", "05/01/2020"];
```

Gostaria de comparar as datas de meu array com as datas de minha lista, caso as datas forem igual quero adicionar a classe evento na linha de minha lista em que a data for igual para que o resultado final seja este

```
<ul id="lista">
    <li><span class="datas">01/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">02/01/2020</span></li>
    <li class="evento"><span class="datas">03/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">04/01/2020</span></li>
    <li class="evento"><span class="datas">05/01/2020</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: O que já tentaste para conseguir isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você queira fazer isso quando a página for carregada, então acho que isso pode te ajudar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var datas_especiais = ["03/01/2020", "05/01/2020"];
  
  $('#lista li .datas').each(function(){
  
    var data = $(this).text();
    if (datas_especiais.includes(data)) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('evento');
      $(this).parent().css('color', 'red'); // Somente para identificar visualmente que está funcionando
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista">
    <li><span class="datas">01/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">02/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">03/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">04/01/2020</span></li>
    <li><span class="datas">05/01/2020</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, funcionou perfeitamente